How to skip migration files depending on a condition or environment in a Java Spring Boot project with Flyway?
I'm new to Java and the Spring Boot environment (Coming from Ruby on Rails). I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Flyway, and while writing tests I'm running on an issue. I have some migrations that are Postgres Specific (making use of partial indexes), so they are failing when running on H2. I searched online for a way to skip these migrations, but found no answer.
So, is there a way to specify that some migrations are only to be run when on an specific database type?

I ended up creating Java migrations when I needed it to run only on Postgres. For this I edited my properties.properties file to add
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration,classpath:db/java
And then in my java/db/migration I created a Base Class for postgres:
package db.migration;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.BaseJavaMigration;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.Context;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public abstract class PostgresBaseMigration extends BaseJavaMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = context.getConnection();
        DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
        String databaseProductName = metaData.getDatabaseProductName();
        String migrationName = getClass().getName();

        if ("PostgreSQL".equalsIgnoreCase(databaseProductName)) {
            execute(context);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Skipping " + migrationName + " migration because its not running on PostgreSQL");
        }
    }

    public abstract void execute(Context context) throws Exception;
}


And then I create my postgres only migrations extending from it.
package db.migration;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.BaseJavaMigration;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.Context;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class V11__AddUniqueIndexes extends PostgresBaseMigration {
    @Override
    public void execute(Context context) throws Exception {
        try (Statement statement = context.getConnection().createStatement()) {
            System.out.println("Running V11__AddUniqueIndexes migration");
            statement.execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_nome_categoria ON hub.categorias(nome) WHERE ativo = true");
            statement.execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_nome_unidade ON hub.unidades(nome) WHERE ativo = true");
            statement.execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_nome_item_dashboard ON hub.itens_dashboard(nome) WHERE ativo = true");
        }
    }
}

